# React and CSS animations

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

When making a state change, React will run a reconciliation algorithm and may completely re-create parts of the DOM.

If I have a CSS animation or transition being applied to a DOM node, how do React developers typically avoid interfering with the DOM during the animation (which might stop the animation)?

Does this "just work", because developers know to only start the animation (e.g. by adding or removing a class) when a specific part of the component lifecycle has completed (e.g. `onComponentDidUpdate`) - i.e. after they can be sure no further major DOM subtree changes will occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this should "just work" with Reacts dom diffing. A more controlled approach would be to move whatever dom that is being animated into it's own component and using the `shouldComponentUpdate` method to control when you let React perform a re-render.